# How to create list of delayed rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

I am trying to make a `ButtonBar` that prints the name of the card in question.

[image]

What I have so far is as follows:

```
myHand = {{1, "Spades"}, {4, "Hearts"}, {5, "Clubs"}, {8, 
   "Spades"}, {9, "Hearts"}, {9, "Spades"}, {11, "Spades"}};

ButtonBar[Table[
  ToString[myHand[[i, 1]]] <> " of " <> ToString[myHand[[i, 2]]] :>
   Print[myHand[[i]]],
  {i, Length@myHand}]
 ]
```

However, instead of working as expected and printing out the name of the card in question, it always prints out `{9, Hearts}`. When I looked into the `FullForm`
 for this it made sense why:

```
ButtonBar[List[RuleDelayed["1 of Spades", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["4 of Hearts", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["5 of Clubs", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["8 of Spades", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["9 of Hearts", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["9 of Spades", Print[Part[myHand, i]]], 
 RuleDelayed["11 of Spades", Print[Part[myHand, i]]]]]
```

The rule is to print out `i`, not the actual number. How can I remedy this so that my `Table` generates a list of actual rules without holding the `i`s back from being evaluated in the `Table`?

Comment: `RuleDelayed` has an attribute `HoldRest` you have tu use `Evaluate` (not always possible) or inject `i` with `With` like `With[{i = i}, "string":>list[[i]]]`

Comment: Ok so I tried all of those, but `Evaluate` didn't work, nor did `With`. Any other ideas?

Comment: `ButtonBar[Table[
  With[{i = i},
   ToString[myHand[[i, 1]]] <> " of " <> ToString[myHand[[i, 2]]] :> 
    Print[myHand[[i]]]], {i, Length@myHand}]]`

Comment: `ButtonBar[(Row[ToString /@ #, " of "] :> Print[#]) & /@ myHand ]` works as you need?

Comment: @Kuba, thank you! I was inserting the `With` at the wrong place. @kguler, your code also works - though looks a bit more complicated

Comment: Another way to force evaluation inside table: `ButtonBar[Table[Row[ToString /@ j, " of "] :> Print[j] /. j -> i, {i, myHand}]]`

Comment: I think, the easiest is to use injector pattern: `Range[Length[myHand]] /. 
 i_Integer :> (ToString[myHand[[i, 1]]] <> " of " <> 
     ToString[myHand[[i, 2]]]) :> Print[myHand[[i]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the values of the iterator variable into held expressions using `With` as suggested in the comments. Alternatively, you can use

```
ButtonBar[Table[Row[ToString /@ #, " of "] :> Print[#] &[i], {i, myHand}]]
```

or

```
ButtonBar[Table[Row[ToString /@ j, " of "] :> Print[j] /. j -> i, {i, myHand}]]
```

You can also create the list of buttons you need without `Table`:

```
ButtonBar[(Row[ToString /@ #, " of "] :> Print[#]) & /@ myHand ]
```

(where `Row[ToString /@ {9,Hearts}, " of "]`, for example gives the same output as your
`ToString[myHand[[5, 1]]] <> " of " <> ToString[myHand[[5, 2]]]`.)